# Save autofilter settings and reapply

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have two Excel tables, and an existing macro that copies data from one of these tables (Table A) and pastes it to bottom of the other (Table B).  I have discovered that if Table A is filtered, this macro will not work because it says that it cannot copy data from a filtered table.  I want to modify my existing macro such that it first copies any filters (any, all, or none of my columns may be filtered when I run the macro), then removes them, then runs my previously programmed activities, then reapplies the saved filters, then gets me a beer.  I'd settle for it doing everything shy of getting me a beer, though.

I assume that this is a common problem, so I have searched for some code that I can place at the beginning and end of my existing code.  I have found the following, but when i add it to my existing code and run the macro, i get an error on the early line which reads:
"currentFiltRange = .Range.Address"
The error states, "Object variable or With block variable not set".  I've very new to VBA and do not know what is wrong with the following code that I copied.

```
Sub CopyThisWeekToRollupAndFilter()


    Dim w As Worksheet
    Dim filterArray()
    Dim currentFiltRange As String
    Dim col As Integer

    Set w = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly")

    ' Capture AutoFilter settings
    With w.AutoFilter
        currentFiltRange = .Range.Address
        With .Filters
            ReDim filterArray(1 To .Count, 1 To 3)
            For f = 1 To .Count
                With .Item(f)
                    If .On Then
                        filterArray(f, 1) = .Criteria1
                        If .Operator Then
                            filterArray(f, 2) = .Operator
                            filterArray(f, 3) = .Criteria2 'simply delete this line to make it work in Excel 2010
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next f
        End With
    End With

    'Remove AutoFilter
    w.AutoFilterMode = False

' Add my existing code here'

' Restore Filter settings
    For col = 1 To UBound(filterArray(), 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(filterArray(col, 1)) Then
            If filterArray(col, 2) Then
                w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter field:=col, _
                Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1), _
                Operator:=filterArray(col, 2), _
                Criteria2:=filterArray(col, 3)
            Else
                w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter field:=col, _
                Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next col


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about tables, they are not filtered ranges, they are `ListObjects` and you would call their range in the following manner

```
currentFiltRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly").ListObjects("Table1").Range.Address
```

Here is a link that gives a VBA guide to tables:
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

Here is a link to an example of what you are trying:
https://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/09/26/copy-excel-table-filter-criteria-vba/

Comment: Thanks.  This fixed my original problem with the "currentFiltRange =" line, however, I'm now getting the same error ("Object variable or With block variable not set") on the next line down, which reads "With.Filters".  Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Oh, and your first link is full of great information.  Thanks.  Your second link is a great piece of code.  However, this is for the purpose of copying filters from one table and pasting them to another.  My application is to copy the filters, remove them, perform some activities, and reapply the filters all to the same table.  I've tried to decipher it, but I guess I'm too novice to know how to modify the linked code for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If AutoFilter is not turned on then `w.AutoFilter` will be `Nothing`

You should add a check to your code to first see if filtering is on or not

E.g.

```
isFiltered = Not w.AutoFilter Is Nothing
```

so you can skip capturing/reapplying the settings

**EDIT:** something like this:

```
Sub CopyThisWeekToRollupAndFilter()


    Dim w As Worksheet
    Dim filterArray()
    Dim currentFiltRange As String
    Dim col As Integer, isFiltered As Boolean

    Set w = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly")
    isFiltered = Not w.AutoFilter Is Nothing 

    If isFiltered Then
    ' Capture AutoFilter settings
    With w.AutoFilter
        currentFiltRange = .Range.Address
        With .Filters
            ReDim filterArray(1 To .Count, 1 To 3)
            For f = 1 To .Count
                With .Item(f)
                    If .On Then
                        filterArray(f, 1) = .Criteria1
                        If .Operator Then
                            filterArray(f, 2) = .Operator
                            filterArray(f, 3) = .Criteria2 'simply delete this line to make it work in Excel 2010
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next f
        End With
    End With
    'Remove AutoFilter
    w.AutoFilterMode = False

    End If  'was filtered


' Add my existing code here'

    If isFiltered Then
    ' Restore Filter settings
    For col = 1 To UBound(filterArray(), 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(filterArray(col, 1)) Then
            If filterArray(col, 2) Then
                w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter field:=col, _
                Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1), _
                Operator:=filterArray(col, 2), _
                Criteria2:=filterArray(col, 3)
            Else
                w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter field:=col, _
                Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next col
    End If 'was filtered


End Sub
```

Comment: Where in my code should this go?  If I put it as the very top line, i get an error "Object variable or With block variable not set".  If i paste it after the start of my With statement I do not get the error any more, but I'm not sure if its doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is a better answer than this, but it may help if you haven't found anything that works. The preset filters will stay the same:

```
Sub Hide_Unhide()
    Dim HiddenColumn() As Long
    Dim HiddenRow() As Long
    Dim colCounter As Long, rowCounter As Long, arrColLength As Long, arrRowLength As Long
    arrColLength = 0
    arrRowLength = 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Unhide columns
    For colCounter = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        If Columns(colCounter).Hidden = True Then
            arrColLength = arrColLength + 1
            ReDim Preserve HiddenColumn(1 To arrColLength)
            HiddenColumn(arrColLength) = colCounter
            Columns(colCounter).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next colCounter

    'Unhide rows
    For rowCounter = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Rows(rowCounter).Hidden = True Then
            arrRowLength = arrRowLength + 1
            ReDim Preserve HiddenRow(1 To arrRowLength)
            HiddenRow(arrRowLength) = rowCounter
            Rows(rowCounter).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next rowCounter

    'Your code here


    'apply hiddend columns
    For colCounter = 1 To arrColLength
        Columns(HiddenColumn(colCounter)).Hidden = True
    Next colCounter

    'apply hiddend rows
    For rowCounter = 1 To arrRowLength
        Rows(HiddenRow(rowCounter)).Hidden = True
    Next rowCounter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```